# Typescript: return type based on input (within an interface)

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface, return

I’m trying to create a function that returns I1 in interface I3, but what does the type I1 is going to contain ?. That **depends on the input** (a string). It is I1, I1 or else I1. I tried using any and Unions but it doesn’t work.

Maybe an overload will work, but how can I define that in the inferface?

```
interface I1<T>{
   //methodes
}
interface I2<T>{
   //methodes
}

type a = { name: string}
type b = { licence: string, registred: boolean }
type c = { grade: number  }

interface I3<T,U>{
   something: () => I2,
   notWorking: <k extends T> (...Props:k[]) => I1<?> //not working and ? can be an a,b or c depending on the input
}
```

Comment: You need an extra generic in notWorking, there is no way Typescript can know the type. Or use a conditional type in the return type

Comment: But how do I assign that extract generic type? Because then I have to use notWorking<a>("t","a") as example. Possible, but I would prefer not do. How do you mean coditional type use?

Comment: Return type is in general based on the input of a function

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand exactly what you want to achieve but I think you can try something like this:

```
interface I3<T,U>{
   something: () => I2<U>,
   notWorking: <k extends T> (...Props:k[]) => I1<k extends string ? a : k extends number ? b : c> //not working and ? can be an a,b or c depending on the input
}
```

Note: You forgot the generic type parameter in the return type of something.